# Are there any alternatives to 'window.onload' in polymer?

Tags: javascript, web, polymer

I am trying to trigger a setTimeout using window.onload, but unable to do so.
Are there any other ways to do this?

```
    window.onload =  function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            alert('Hide that spinner!'); 
        }, 3000);
        console.log('After 3 seconds');
    };
```

Comment: Are you using Polymer 1 or 2? Is it possible to see where you are trying to run the above code?

Comment: Polymer 1, I am trying to run this in 'ready: function () {} ' in the script of same html which is being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Polymer 1, you can use `ready` callback function:

```
ready: function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        alert('Hide that spinner!'); 
    }, 3000);
    console.log('After 3 seconds');
  }
```

It is called after property values are set and local DOM is initialized.

Comment: Thanks, I did more research and this makes sense now :)